# "Expected resource of type layout/menu" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

```
    package com.example.nimehr.streaming;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.example.videostream.VideoViewActivity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;

public MainActivity() {
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(2130903040);
    this.button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    this.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VideoViewActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.getMenuInflater().inflate(2131165184, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

I'm getting the error "Expected resource of type layout/menu" at `2130903040` in `this.setContentView(2130903040);` and `2131165184`in `this.getMenuInflater().inflate(2131165184, menu);` respectively. I fixed it here ***this.button = (Button)this.findViewById(2131230720);*** by changing it to R.id.MyButton

Answer (score 1):

DO **not** do it this way:

```
this.setContentView(2130903040);
```

`R` class exists for a reason to avoid explicitly using ids like this, and to replace it with a more readable cleaner code:

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.layout_name_here);
```

From the docs:

> When your application is compiled, `aapt` generates the R class, which contains resource IDs for all the resources in your res/ directory.

Comment: This fixed the first one but im still getting Expected resource of type menu on the second one.

Comment: Hah, well, the same thing, just use the proper `R.menu.whatever` id or whatever you're inflating.